# When I use a db2 insert statement it only runs if I use single quotes, but I don't want single quotes in the value that is inserted into the table

Tags: insert, db2, single-quotes

I am trying to insert values into a table on a db2 db, and its inputting single quotes.. argggh
So I am able to insert values using 
insert into table abc.house (house_name, is_active) values ('Treasure', 1);

however when selecting the value in the table is 'Treasure' which I don't want those lovely quotes.

If I try to use:
insert into table abc.house (house_name, is_active values (Treasure, 1);
I get an error
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=TREASURE, DRIVER=4

Any solutions? Thanks, JT

Answer (score 1):

so i learned that the sql UI that was set up, was done so that for Varchar values single quotes are part of the return from a query.  The UI shows 'Treasure', whereas if I query on the command line the return is simply Treasure
Good to go.  using insert statement with single quotes around the value is good syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. We MUST put single quotes across char/varchar/blob data.

Comment: Thank you @yogeshDb2 I always used single quotes for insert before, but I couldn't understand how to not have single quotes as part of the value. But I found that the gui tool automatically added the single quotes for varchar2 values. yet the clp showed the true values. I appreciate your answer.